# How to make a modal dialog and receive feedback from the child form (like folderbrowser control)

Tags: c#, forms, directory

So I'm trying to make a folderbrowser for my custom application in C# and the folderbrowser thing is okay, but I want to set it up like how the default one acts.
According to @Kevin I am trying to make a modal dialog.

```
   // I create the folderbrowser control and await the directory 
   string CreateFileDialog(bool allowFixedDrives)
    {
        FolderBrowser fb = new FolderBrowser(this, allowFixedDrives);
        fb.Show();

        //return THE_SELECTED_FOLDER_DIR;
        return "";
    }
```

So in the folderbrowser there is a boolean to allow fixed drives and also a reference to the parent form:

```
// Create the control and receive whether or not it should read fixed drives and also get a reference to the parent control.
public FolderBrowser(Form1 frm1, bool allowFixed)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.allowFixed = allowFixed;
        frm1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

I freeze the main form when this dialog is created. *If the user closes the form, it will return null or "" and if the user presses okay, it should return the selected directory (where THE_SELECTED_FOLDER_DIR is).*

Does anyone know how I can cleanly implement a dialog that sends feedback to the parent form?
Feel free to ask if you are as confused as I am :)

Comment: What you are trying to make is a modal dialog.

Comment: Yeah. Okay. So how do I implement this? Also thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Use the Form.ShowDialog method rather than the Form.Show method (you pass in a reference to the parent, this).

Comment: That should work, but then I need to send the directory that the user has navigated to back to the main form?

Comment: return fb.SelectedPath ?

Comment: Create a public method on your form that internally calls ShowDialog and returns the folder information.

Comment: huh. Smart. I'd have to do this before the form is disposed right? What happens if it gets unloaded before I can access the variable?

Comment: I see now. That's pretty cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a rather interesting discussion with @Kevin, I've decided that the best way to go about this would be to call a public function in the form and then show it. Kinda hard to explain, so I'll show you:
NB: I think this should be kept open just in case someone has the same issues I did...

So I want to simply get a selected folder name and I'll display that selected folder on a text control for example:

```
        bool invalid = false;
        string value = CreateFileDialog(true, out invalid);
        if (!invalid)
        {
            txt_File.Text = value;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A folder was not selected.");
        }
```

Okay, so I'm creating a dialog. I check if the dialog was closed without selecting a file and display a messagebox if it's invalid....

```
    string CreateFileDialog(bool allowFixedDrives, out bool invalid)
    {
        FolderBrowser fb = new FolderBrowser(this, allowFixedDrives);

        return fb.ShowForm(out invalid);
    }
```

Now here is where it gets interesting. I create the dialog here and call a function on the form to actually show it, but I pass a boolean as an out variable to detect if it was closed without selecting a file.
And finally:

```
    public string ShowForm(out bool a)
    {
        ShowDialog();
        frm1.Enabled = true;

        if (!Directory.Exists(selectedFolder))
        {
            a = true;
            return selectedFolder;
        }
        else
        {
            a = false;
            return selectedFolder;
        }
    }
```

I return the selected folder name if the user pressed OK, otherwise don't return it and also set the out parameter to false.
There you have it.
I'd like to thank everyone who pitched in here, namely @Kevin.